# What does VS Code's setting search.runInExtensionHost do?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out what the VS Code's setting `search.runInExtensionHost` does. I've searched Google, VS Code's [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/extension-host) and Stack Overflow and got nothing. The only mention of something remotely related to this setting is this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47058).

It seems to change the search processor to Ripgrep, but I have no idea if that's it, if that's something merely related to that or if I'm missing the mark entirely.

Could someone please provide a clear explanation and use case for this setting?